# Jquery mouse hover color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am converting flash ad into html5 ad.

I am copying this demo [link](http://platform.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.Preview.Web/AdPreview.aspx?reportinteractions=0&adid=20986603).

I just want to make mouse hover effect. In the demo if mouse goes to details text then the whole banner color changes to black and text of disclaimer appears. How to implement this?

This is my code [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/24/)

```
<div id = "wrapper" >       
 <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="text">
        <img id="Image_Car" src="http://i.share.pho.to/c43dc6d7_o.png" />
    </div>  
     <div id="Div1">
      <p id="discalimer">Details*</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `the whole banner color changes to black` mean? You can't change the border color because that's not a CSS border: it's part of the picture you're using for the background. Do you want the inside of the box to be black?

Comment: why are you animating the image to left if you want it to go black? can you explain bit more clearly on what animation you need?

Comment: yes AstroCB i want to change the box only .

Comment: @sree can you please see the demo link if you move your mouse on details text then box changes to black and disclaimer text appears

Comment: its a flash ad. its working fine on every browser

Comment: @user3718016 Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/veDY6/8/)? You can't change anything inside the box because the box is an image.

Comment: i have updated my code http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/13/ now is it possible to change the inside of box to black and white color disclaimer text like in demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need animations, you can just do this:

```
$('#disclaimer').hover(
    function () {
        $('#wrapper').addClass('hovered');
    }, function () {
        $('#wrapper').removeClass('hovered');
    }
);
```

And then use CSS for the styling:

```
.copy {display: none;color: white; padding: 10px;}
.hovered .copy { display: block; }
.hovered #mainContainer { background: black; border-color: black; }
.hovered #Image_Car { display: none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/27/

Comment: @ i want exactly like this http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/17/ but also want to hide the image

Comment: @user3718016 In that case, you just need to change the CSS to do whatever styling you need. See updated answer above.

Comment: actually i have updated my code http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/24/ but it is showing borders i dont want to show borders as well

Comment: @user3718016 Again, in that case, you just need to modify the CSS to do that. See update above, and whatever you do, please correct the spelling of "discalimer". I have corrected it three times.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your issue correctly this may help:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/9/)**

jQuery has a built in `.hover()` method. Here I'm using it to toggle a class on the wrapper and show the hidden copy block.

JS:

```
$('#discalimer').hover(
    function () {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('hovered');
        $('.copy').show();
    }, function () {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('hovered');
        $('.copy').hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: exactly i want like this but i also want to hide the image as well

Comment: can you check this http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/17/ its perfect but also want to hide the image

Comment: @user3718016 [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/17/). Just use `.hide()`. You also might want to change the `cursor` for the disclaimer to `pointer` so that there isn't the text pointer there while they're hovering.

Comment: actually i have updated my code http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/24/ but it is showing borders i dont want to show borders as well

Comment: @user3718016, hiding the border should be easy. We're already toggling a class on hover, so we'll just have that class contain a `border: 0;`. See this example: [http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/28/](http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/28/), checkout line 41.

Answer (score 1):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/21/)

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mainContainer" class="mcClass">
        <div id="text">
            <img id="Image_Car" src="http://i.share.pho.to/c43dc6d7_o.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="Div1">
            <p id="discalimer">Details*</p>
            <p id="realDisclaimer" style="display:none">This is the real disclaimer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height:250px;
    position: absolute;
}

#realDisclaimer{
    color:white;
}
#Div1 {
    top:142px;
    left:76px;
    width:50px;
    height:30px;
    position: absolute;
}
.unselectable, #Div1 p {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none;
    /* IE10+ */
    /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor:default;
}
.mcHoverState {
    background-color:black;
}
.mcClass {
    background: url('https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes/Site-8188/Type-0/5fefb401-b187-4d82-b4db-cbd2ef29cc48.gif');
}
#mainContainer {
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
#Image_Car {
    position:absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:60px 8px;
    left: -120px;
}
```

js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     bannerAnimation();
     $("#Div1").mouseenter(

     function (evt) {
         $("#text").hide();
         $("#mainContainer").removeClass("mcClass").addClass("mcHoverState");
         $("#discalimer").hide();
         $("#realDisclaimer").show();
     })
         .mouseleave(

     function (evt) {
         $("#realDisclaimer").hide();
         $("#text").show();
         $("#discalimer").show();
         $("#mainContainer").removeClass("mcHoverState").addClass("mcClass");
     });
 });

 function bannerAnimation() {
     //Jquery Animation
     $("#Image_Car").animate({
         left: "30"
     }, 500, function () {
         $("#Image_Car").animate({
             left: "10"
         }, 200);
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Again!**
*did you use that windy plugin or no?*

i didn't understand what you want but maybe this is your answer:

first you should know about color:color in web is Red Green Blue, You can take the X-point and Y-point of your jquery code and write some math formal for that:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/veDY6/11/)

```
#wrapper:hover #mainContainer
{

background:silver;
}
#wrapper:hover
{
 background:black !important;
   box-shadow:3px 3px 3px rgba(186,202,228,1);

 color:white;
}
```

and a demo in black color [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/veDY6/14/)

Comment: yes i am trying windy effect as well :) and can you check my updated codE

Comment: i dont want this i want something like this one http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/17/ but also want to hide the image